# calculating weighted average of cost change

Tags: powerbi, dax, analytics, measure, weighted-average

I have a dataset in power bi in which I want to calculate the weighted average of change of cost when it happened in the data
I have 3 columns in dataset movement , cost and cost change
I have calculated closing of stock with the help of ( movement + sale + sale return) and my formula for weighted average would be like
Sum Product = calculate(sumx(table1 , cost * closing Stock ))
and weighted avg would be
WA= Divide(Sum Product , Closing Stock) but problem is that its not getting changed in value for months
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8kZk.png)

help would be highly appreciated .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this just a repost of your question from two days ago?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69792809/weighted-average-for-cost-change

Comment: yes i'm struggling to find answer that's why i'm asking again n again